# sed syntax to update the below xml statement

Tags: regex, xml, sed

I need to update few attribute values in an XML file and was thinking to leverage sed for doing find and replace. I was unable to achieve my desired output.

**Current**:

```
<categoryName>Mobiles & Tablets</categoryName>
```

**Replace** with

```
<categoryName>Mobiles</categoryName>
```

Comment: You may want to indicate if tags occur on one line or they can split across multiple lines.

Comment: Is your requirement to change the specific text `Mobiles & Tablets` to `Mobiles` anywhere it occurs in your file or to update text within `<categoryName>` tags or to remove all occurrences of `&` followed by text within any tags or something else? Edit your question to state your requirements because an answer that just does `echo "<categoryName>Mobiles</categoryName>"` would satisfy what you've told us so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to search and replace.

```
sed  -i 's|Mobiles & Tablets|Mobiles|g' filename
```

Use this to save your output in another file and compare with original if this is what you want. Later you can replace old file with new file

```
sed  's|Mobiles & Tablets|Mobiles|g' filename >newfile
```

Edit: Added example

```
$> cat tt01
<subCategoryId>175</subCategoryId>
   <categoryId>12</categoryId>
<categoryName>Mobiles & Tablets</categoryName>
<mrp>1111</mrp>
<offerPrice>777</offerPrice>
$> 
$> sed -i 's|Mobiles & Tablets|Mobiles|g' tt01
$> cat tt01
<subCategoryId>175</subCategoryId>
   <categoryId>12</categoryId>
<categoryName>Mobiles</categoryName>
<mrp>1111</mrp>
<offerPrice>777</offerPrice>
```

Comment: You should also use the -i parameter for saving it.

Comment: Thanks It worked. The reason being & was being treated as &amp; Thus causing it not to work.

Comment: If it worked, please accept it as answer by clicking on `tick` symbol on left of the answer, so the question can be closed. Thanks.